# An irrational number $x$ such that $x^x$ is rational

Tags: real-numbers

I can show that there exists an irational number $x$ such that $x^x$ is rational. But I have no example. Can you give a pricise example of such number $x$?

Comment: Hi @sara.T and Welcome to MSE. Take a [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to the site and read some questions/answers. These things will help you to understand the site in a better way.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029536/on-ab-mid-a-b-notin-mathbbq-and-ab-in-mathbb-q) is where I already asked a related question.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX This is a related but different question since it requires $a=b$.

Comment: @dxiv I see that now.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX hi, I think my question is different.

Comment: @Sara.T it is different, but related. Sorry about that.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. sorry if I did somthing wrong

Comment: Do you know the intermediate-value theorem?

Comment: @Airymouse I don't think that applies here, since the OP is asking about *irrational* $x$ specifically. IVT implies that for some $x$, $x^x$ is rational, but how do we know that $x$ isn't itself rational?

Comment: @Sara.T, it is moral duty of users on MSE to welcome new users on site and tell them about site. You have not done anything wrong.

Comment: @dxiv which part of that page answers my question? It only says such $x$ can not be algebraic.

Comment: @Sara.T I had deleted that comment already.

Comment: This question deserve +1, at least from me.

Comment: @ Noah Schweber Of course. My mistake.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The positive real solution to $x^x=2$ is irrational.

Proof:

Assume $x=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ have no common factor but $1$ then:

$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{p}=2^{q}$$

We must have $p^p=q^p2^q$

Note $p>q$ because $x>1$ (this can be shown).

Then $p$ must be even. So we may set $p=2k$.

$$(2k)^{2k}=q^p2^q$$

$$2^{2k}k^{2k}=q^{2k}2^q$$

$$2^{2k-q}k^{2k}=q^{2k}$$

Then $q$ must be even. Contradiction.

Note:

We have $x^x=2$, then $x \ln x=\ln 2$ and $\ln xe^{\ln x}=2$ so using the lambert W function:

$$\ln x=W(\ln 2)$$

$$x=e^{W(\ln 2)}=\frac{\ln (2)}{W(\ln 2)}$$

Comment: you got mine too

Comment: I can not see that how does it relevant to my question ?

Comment: The irrational number $x$ produces a rational number $x^x=2$ @Sara.T

Comment: @Sara.T You can write $x$ explicitly in terms of the Lambert $W$ (or productlog) function: $x = e^{W(\ln 2)}$. The answer above proves that $x$ is irrational and $x^x=2$ as can be verified on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(e%5E(W(log+2)))%5E(e%5E(W(log+2)))).

Comment: As I said in my question I knew such a number do exists but I am looking for an example.

Comment: @Sara.T: this IS an example.

Comment: @YvesDaoust disagree, it only shows that an example EXISTS

Comment: @Sara.T: this number exists thanks to the continuity of $x^x$. You confuse existence and closed-form formula.

Comment: @Sara.T  I have edited maybe this will satisfy you.

Comment: @Sara.T I gave the explicit expression for $x$ in my previous comment.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I agree with sara as OP clearly want an example which follow the condition mentioned. But the answers do not address that thing.(sorry if I m wrong)

Comment: @THELONEWOLF.: $x$ is irrational while $x^x$ is rational. What other condition are you referring to ? The solution is constructive as $x^x=2$ unambiguously defines a real number.

Comment: I m not saying anything else.I agree that question specifically mention that  x is irrational while x^x is rational, but I think OP is demanding for an example in numbers. A number which satisfy the above mentioned condition.

Comment: It might be quicker to say $p^p=q^p2^q\implies q\mid p^p\implies q=1$ since $(p,q)=1$, and then note that $2$ is not of the form $p^p$ for any integer $p$.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF.: such a number cannot be written down as it is irrational.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think the issue arises from using multiple representations of the variable (x), even though these representations are equivalent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, please don't laugh at me if I m arguing about a wrong thing. But $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational but we can still write it.

Comment: @floorcat: I think the issue comes from the OP wanting a closed-form expression without stating it and believing that the root of an equation is not a valid definition.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF.: I can write $x^x=2$, can't I ? By the way, $\sqrt2$ is originally defined as the solution of $x^2=2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust A closed expression is an elegant answer to this question, given the parameters.  Elegance is relative though, but it seems you make it difficult to glance over this answer and immediately see the example she's asking for.

Comment: Maybe you can,But still I can't get you. Please elaborate a bit, I know you will say that "see my answer", but  I can't get it from there too.

Comment: @floorcat: closed-form was not specified. The OP has to know and accept that there are other ways to define a number, for instance infinite series. Anyway the answerer gave an analytical expression too.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not saying, and did not say that closed form was specific in OP.  But it also did not specify open-form and yet we both answered in our own ways.  I will not engage in speculations about what the OP *should* or *should not* know or accept.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Thanks, But I can not accept it as an answer to my question.

Comment: @Sara.T Just curious, if you `can not accept it as an answer` then what answer were you actually looking for? You should edit into the question what exactly are your requirements for an answer to qualify.

Comment: I find it very interesting that the most upvoted answer has been clearly rejected by the author of this question.

Comment: @floorcat That's simply because *after* receiving a correct and deservedly upvoted answer, the OP had a change of heart and decided that s/he meant to ask a presumably *different* question (which hasn't been articulated, yet).

Comment: sure.  She doesn't understand her own question, which you know better enough to give an answer she doesn't want.  Makes sense.  Good night.

Comment: Thank you! And happy new year. @gowrath

Answer (score 6):

As $x^x$ is a continous function, $1^1=1$ and $2^2=4$, then there is an $x$ such that

$$x^x=2.$$

As the function is monotonic in this range, the solution is unique.

This number is irrational, otherwise let $x$ be the irreducible fraction $p/q$:

$$\left(\frac pq\right)^{p/q}=2$$ implies

$$p^p=2^qq^p.$$

Then $p$ is even, $p=2r$ with $q$ odd, and

$$2^{2r}r^{2r}=2^qq^p,$$
so that $q$ is even !

Comment: Crossed with Ahmed S. Attaalla.

Comment: The conclusion depends on $q$ being strictly less than $2r$.  I think it would help to make this explicit.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to prove the more general: if $x$ is an algebraic irrational then $x^x$ is irrational.

Comment: @BarryCipra: I don't see why. As $q^p$ is odd, $q$ is also the multiplicity of $2$ in the LHS, which is certainlly even.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, ah, that argument works as well.  I was thinking of rewriting $2^{2r}r^{2r}=2^qq^p$ as $2^{2r-q}r^{2r}=q^p$.  But I kind of like your way:  If $q$ is odd, it must be even!